# Rails do not reload the content after a new JQuery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm developing a web app with RoR and i would like to implement a simple message system, but i've some problems at displaying messages between two users. After the AJAX request the HTML page render the result of controller's action but as soon as i resend another request the content doesn't change.

That's my AJAX request code
(id1 and id2 are the two users involved in the conversation)

```
function test(id1, id2) {
    var id = { 'id1': id1, 'id2': id2 }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/conversaziones/index",
        type: "POST",
        data: id,
        success: function (html) {
            $("#index").replaceWith(html);
        }
    })
}
```

This is my HTML line calling the request:

```
<% @user.where(id: trova_user_id(conversazione.destinatario_id)).find_each do |utente| %>
<a href="" onclick="test(<%= current_id %> ,<%= trova_user_id(conversazione.destinatario_id) %>); return false;"> <%= utente.nome %> <%= utente.cognome %> </a>
```

This is the controller action called through routes

```
def load_conversazione
@conversazione=Conversazione.all
   @msg=@conversazione.where(user_id: params[:id1], destinatario_id: converti_mail_id(params[:id2])).or(@conversazione.where(user_id: converti_mail_id(params[:id1]), user_id: params[:id2]))
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => false }
   end
end
```

And this is the action's view

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="registrazione">
            <table>
                <% @msg.find_each do | messaggi | %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= messaggi.messaggio %> </td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The first time i click one of the name listed the conversation appears but when i try to click another name the conversation is not reloaded even if the server recieve the new request.
How can i fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I think there are missing pieces in the code, share a little bit more. For instance, I don't where the element with id `index` is; I don't either see the `load_conversazione ` partial that's returned; and also the url in your ajax is `"/conversaziones/index"` whereas the action in your controller is `load_conversazione `, do you have your routes properly set up ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gEWvLSmk thats the full html page code.
The load_conversaziones is not a partial but a page rendered into a div

Comment: is your `load_conversazione ` action mapped to the `"/conversaziones/index"` route ?. or are they different actions ?.

Comment: load_conversazione is loaded as the AJAX request has been sent through routes post "/conversaziones/index" => "conversaziones#load_conversazione"

Comment: got it, I think you need to replace your js from `$("#index").replaceWith(html);` to `$("#index").html(html);`, because right now the element with id `index` is gone after the first click.